# SonarQube Pre-commit analysis for JavaScript

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint-vs

I need to find a way to do a pre-commit incremental analysis with rules supplied by SonarQube 5.4 hosted on a server. The most important files to analyze are JavaScript files, and we are working in C# using ASP.NET framework, so installing Eclipse for a large team is not feasible.

I have tried Sonar-Scanner 2.8, but it does not pick up the analysis already done on the server (shows all issues as new), and it also does not react to exclusions. Documentation on that matter is outdated, as, for example, *incremental* analysis is not supported anymore, and *issues* analysis is not documented properly regarding what it does,

Some relevant parts from *sonar-project.properties*:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/Scripts/*angular*.js,**/Scripts/*bootstrap*.js,**/Scripts/*d3*.js,**/Scripts/*jquery*.js,**/Scripts/*modernizr*.js,**/Scripts/*respond*.js,**/Scripts/*toolkit*.js,**/tbshared/**/*.*,**/Scripts/*reference*.js,**/packages/**/*.*,**/Scripts/angular*.map,**/Scripts/*.json,**/Scripts/*.css,**/Scripts/i18n/*.* 
...    
#Enable HTML
    sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true

    #Enable console output
    sonar.issuesReport.console.enable

    #Enable incremental analysis
    sonar.analysis.mode=issues
```

Comment: It will be nice to provide a link on documents, when you state that they are outdated. Regarding the question - maybe you should have a look at http://www.sonarlint.org/commandline/index.html and http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Local+and+Branch+Analysis and http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin ?

Comment: I converted comment into answer, so that maybe you can mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: I am still researching on that matter, other than a json example on the front page of SonarLint, is there a a full list of parameters that json config file accepts and maybe some examples of that configuration? Thank you!

Comment: What kind of more parameters you are searching and why? According to my understanding: as soon as project will be connected with server in SonarLint for command-line - it will be aware of issues recorded on server as well as exclusions.

Comment: For example, now I am having problems with "Invalid characters". I need to configure the encoding, but there are no sonarlint examples to do so, which just leaves me guessing...

Comment: Page states `You can list the accepted arguments with sonarlint -h` and this command gives me `--charset <name> Character encoding of the source files`.

Comment: That's a good point.. It did not resolve the problem though.. It somehow seems like LIit is analyzing everything, including the zip files, despite the fact that it says that it is in a connected mode.. Anyway, will continue looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one day [SonarLint for Visual Studio](http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/) will be extended to cover more languages than just C#.

But as of today you can take a look at:

- [SonarLint for Command Line](http://www.sonarlint.org/commandline/index.html)
- [GitHub Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin)

All those links are available in [SonarQube documentation on page "Local and Branch Analysis"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Local+and+Branch+Analysis).